# GetFocus на wxStringProperty

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Есть таблица `wxPropertyGrid` с различными полями (`wxStringProperty`, `wxUIntProperty`, `wxBoolProperty` и т.д.).

Метод `Get/SetFocus()` они не имеют.

Могу ли я программно задать фокус?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

использовал метод SelectProperty()